# Existence of a connection between 2 nodes

Tags: python, graph, connection, nodes

I want to find if a connection exists between any 2 nodes of a network, and I can't seem to understand where I went wrong in the check_connection function!
Please Help!

```
b=0

def make_link(G, node1, node2):
  if node1 not in G:
    G[node1] = {}
  (G[node1])[node2] = 1
  if node2 not in G:
    G[node2] = {}
  (G[node2])[node1] = 1
  return G
```

########### Why does this function iterate to infinity?

```
def check_connection(G, v1, v2):
  # Return True if v1 is connected to v2 in G
  # or False if otherwise

  global b

  for a in G[v1].keys():

    if a==v2:
        return True

    if b==a:
        continue

    else:
        b=v1
        check_connection(G,a,v2)
  return False

edges = [('a', 'g'), ('a', 'd'), ('g', 'c'), ('g', 'd'), ('b', 'f'), ('f', 'e'), ('e', 'h')]

G = {}

for v1, v2 in edges:
  make_link(G, v1, v2)

print check_connection(G,edges[0][0],edges[4][1])
```

Comment: Could it be because you have called your function (check_connection(G,a,v2)) within your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graph has a loop a->g->d->a. Your function keeps literally looping around. You should maintain a set of all visited nodes, not just of the most recent node, and check if the next node has been already visited. So, change `b=0` to `b=set()`, `b==a` to `a in b`, and `b=v1` to `b.add(v1)`.

Comment: It still returns False for any search operation, as after the end of the for loop, the last recursion will throw the return False statement, even if its true. i.e. its returning True in the 2nd last recursion if we check connectivity between a and c, and in the last recursion, which actually sends the value back to where the function is called it returns false.

Comment: Your recursive function is incorrect. The most striking mistake: you never check the value returned by the nested call to `check_connection`.The algorithm you are trying to implement is called depth-first search (DFS). Perhaps you should search for its pseudo-code, and many Python implementations exist, too.